# Meaning of the term "deterministic" in visual cryptography

Tags: cryptography

In the paper " Random Grid and Deterministic Visual Cryptography with Enhanced color patterns" 
  http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2743130;

uses the term deterministic. Can anyone help me to understand the significance of the  term **deterministic**. Thanks in advance

Comment: Deterministic encryption is not probabilistic. This means that the same plain text under the same key becomes the same cipher text. CBC-mode is not deterministic, e.g., while ECB is.

Comment: @HennoBrandsa, thank you for your answer. Actually I am new in visual cryptography. Sir I have some questions on visual cryptography scheme and VCRG. May I ask you these questions?

Comment: You can always ask questions on this forum, but probably the cryptography stack exchange is better for such specific questions.